# SilverStripe ModelAdmin

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am new to silverstripe framework and trying to fetch a list of menu in the admin panel.

I found lots of example to show menu on front-end by Menu(1) and Menu(2) etc. but did not get any sample code to fetch same menu array in admin model.

The code I tried is:

```
public function getCMSfields() {
    $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));
    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
        TextField::create('Name'),
        DropdownField::create('URL')
            ->setSource(SiteTree::get()),

    ));

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [`TreeDropdownField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-TreeDropdownField.html) is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

ModelAdmin is mainly there to manage DataObjects and not Pages. Have a look at the [Docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/modeladmin/) and this [Lesson](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/introduction-to-modeladmin) to learn more about ModelAdmin.

But if you want to manage pages in a ModelAdmin, you could do it like that

```
class MyPageAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

  ...
  ...

  private static $managed_models = array(
    'Page'
  );

  public function getList() {
    $list = parent::getList();

    if($this->modelClass == 'Page'){
      $list = $list->filter('ParentID', '1');
    }

    return $list;
  }
}
```

To manage only children from a specific page, use the getList() function and filter your list after your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is also (albiet for an older version) this tutorial http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-using-model-admin-and-url-segments-to-create-a-product-catalogue/ from ssbits